# Using disqus over https - trouble uploading images

Tags: https, disqus

We are loading the disqus embed.js library over https...going as far as to specify https as opposed to leaving the protocol out:

```
  <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var disqus_shortname = 'our-shortname';
    (function() {
      var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
      dsq.src = 'https://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js?https';
      (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
  </script>
```

Everything works fine with loading in the comments iframe...the problem occurs when someone tries to include an image in their comment.

It appears that the disqus iframe is posting the image using http, as opposed to https, so the image preview that is returned is being blocked by the browser (because the iframe was loaded from https), and disqus is seeing it as an error and throwing up a warning message:

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBlYN.png

We confirmed that if we served the site over http and loaded embed.js from http as well, everything works fine.  So it looks pretty definite that the mismatched protocol is the issue.

Is there any way to make sure the disqus code properly uses https when doing the image upload??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't currently have support for https image uploads. We're aware that this limitation is kind of a bummer, so this shouldn't be the case forever.

Comment: thanks for the heads up...is it possible to turn off the image upload feature then?

Comment: Yep, uncheck 'Enable media attachments' on this page: http://disqus.com/admin/settings/